# How to get OffsetDateTime->LocalDateTime and save this as UTC?

Tags: java, parsing, utc, datetimeoffset, localdate

I didn't find a suitable answer for my problem even after a lot of searching.
It's a DateConvertUtil class in a Java API.
This is kind of a refactoring/feature task.

I have a Method, which parses a given date String, formats it with the help of another Method and returns a LocalDateTime(this kinda has to be - too much dependencies).

I want to get the Timezone of the User, convert(or maybe don't) to LocalDateTime BUT don't want to save the LocalDateTime but the UTC one everytime.

My Problem now is how to approach this.
I don't seem to get the Offset.

The parser was working before, but only for LocaldateTime, the formatter works too.

So far I have

```
    public static LocalDateTime parseIso8601(String date) {
        if (date == null || date.isEmpty() || date.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") || date.length() < 10) throw new
                IllegalArgumentException("Date cannot by empty or smaller than 10 characters for parsing! Minimum date " +
                "is yyyy-MM-dd");


        LocalDateTime localDateTime;
        OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.now();
        offsetDateTime.toInstant().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);

        localDateTime = offsetDateTime.toLocalDateTime();

        return localDateTime.parse(date, buildIso8601Formatter());
```

So I have read some about ZonedDateTime and Timestamps, but maybe I just can't think straight.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not very clear. You may be after something like the following:

```
    ZoneId userTimeZone = ZoneId.systemDefault();

    String date = "2019-12-25";

    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDate.parse(date).atStartOfDay();
    System.out.println("localDateTime: " + localDateTime);

    OffsetDateTime utcDateTime = localDateTime.atZone(userTimeZone)
            .toOffsetDateTime()
            .withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    System.out.println("utcDateTime: " + utcDateTime);
```

When I run this snippet in my time zone (Europe/Copenhagen), the output is:

> ```
> localDateTime: 2019-12-25T00:00
> utcDateTime: 2019-12-24T23:00Z
> ```

You said:

> I want to get the Timezone of the User, …

The way to do this differs. In a standalone application you may try `ZonedId.systemDefault()` as in the above code. It gives you the default time zone of the JVM, which may or may not agree with what the user intends. And the setting can be changed at any time from another part of your program or another program running in the same JVM, so is fragile. On a server that has users in different time zones `ZoneId.systemDefault()` won’t work at all. You need to have the time zone passed from some client/browser. There are ways, and you may search for the way to do it in your setup.

> … BUT don't want to save the LocalDateTime but the UTC one everytime.

That’s good, using UTC is recommended. Again the way to do this depends on your setup. If saving into an SQL database you can save either an `OffsetDateTime` or an `Instant` (provided that you’re using a JDBC 4.2 compliant driver, which is highly likely) so the above code may suffice. If you need to store the date and time as a string, use `Instant.toString()` for producing a string in ISO 8601 format. I recommend against using a `LocalDateTime` for you date and time in UTC since it doesn’t “know” itself that it is in UTC, which makes the risk of an error too great. Other examples:

```
    Instant utcInstant = localDateTime.atZone(userTimeZone).toInstant();
    System.out.println("utcInstant: " + utcInstant);

    String utcDateTimeString = utcDateTime.toString();
    System.out.println("utcDateTimeString: " + utcDateTimeString);
```

> ```
> utcInstant: 2019-12-24T23:00:00Z
> utcDateTimeString: 2019-12-24T23:00Z
> ```

The name `utcInstant`is really either redundant or nonsense since an `Instant` on one hand is independent of time zones, on the other hand always prints in UTC. I couldn’t readily think of a better name, sorry. Anuway it is fine for storing if you can in your setup.

Comment: I did some research and I understand why I should not use LocalDateTime for UTC. But in my case I have to convert it to LocalDateTime. The Problem is pretty obvious that I have trouble calculating the correct time because it is always lost after converting. I think the best (for future purposes) thing would be to refactor the method and it's dependencies to store it as Instant or OffsetDateTime like you said.